# basic calendar build - outputting mysql events data using pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to build a calender step by step, basically I just need to output my events data in a really basic calender which looks like this.

[image]
I've built the calendar okay, but my problem is that I cannot get it to display the events next to the dates. This is my database connection php file, **the issue may be caused by this fil**e because I cannot display my mysql data - sorry I dont know pdo at all.

```
<?php

class DB_Connect {
    /**
     * Stores a database object
     *
     * @var object A database object
     */
    protected $db;
    /**
     * Checks for a DB object or creates one if one isn't found
     *
     * @param object $dbo A database object
     */
    protected function __construct($dbo=NULL)
    {
        if ( is_object($db) )
        {
            $this->db = $db;
        }
        else
        {
            // Constants are defined in /sys/config/db-cred.inc.php
            $dsn = "mysql:host=" . DB_HOST . ";dbname=" . DB_NAME;
            try
            {
                $this->db = new PDO($dsn, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
            }
            catch ( Exception $e )
            {
                // If the DB connection fails, output the error
                die ( $e->getMessage() );
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

this is my calender.php code which creates the necessary classes for the calender dates and events. The issue could be within the **_loadEventData** function

```
<?php

include_once '../sys/class/class.db_connect.inc.php';
include_once '../sys/config/db-cred.inc.php';
include_once '../sys/class/class.event.inc.php';

class Calendar extends DB_Connect
{
    private $_useDate;
    private $_m;
    private $_y;
    private $_daysInMonth;
    private $_startDay;

    public function __construct($dbo=NULL, $useDate=NULL)
    {
        //Call the parent constructor to check for a db obj

        parent::__construct($dbo);
        //Gather and store data relevant to the month

        if ( isset($useDate) )
        {
            $this->_useDate = $useDate;
        }
        else
        {
            $this->_useDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        }
        // Convert to a timestamp, then determine the month&year to use when building the calendar

        $ts = strtotime($this->_useDate);
        $this->_m = date('m', $ts);
        $this->_y = date('Y', $ts);
        //Determine how many days are in the month

        $this->_daysInMonth = cal_days_in_month(
            CAL_GREGORIAN,
            $this->_m,
            $this->_y
        );
        // Determine what weekday the month starts on

        $ts = mktime(0, 0, 0, $this->_m, 1, $this->_y);
        $this->_startDay = date('w', $ts);
    }
    //generate calendar


    private function _loadEventData($id=NULL)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT
    `event_id`, `event_title`, `event_desc`,
    `event_start`, `event_end`
    FROM `events`";
        //If an event ID is supplied, add a WHERE clause so only that event is returned


        if ( !empty($id) )
        {
            $sql .= "WHERE `event_id`=:id LIMIT 1";
        }
        //Otherwise, load all events for the month in use

        else
        {
            //Find the first and last days of the month

            $start_ts = mktime(0, 0, 0, $this->_m, 1, $this->_y);
            $end_ts = mktime(23, 59, 59, $this->_m+1, 0, $this->_y);
            $start_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $start_ts);
            $end_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $end_ts);
            //Filter events to only those happening in the currently selected month

            $sql .= "WHERE `event_start`
    BETWEEN '$start_date'
    AND '$end_date'
    ORDER BY `event_start`";
        }
        try
        {
            $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            //Bind the parameter if an ID was passed

            if ( !empty($id) )
            {
                $stmt->bindParam(":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            }
            $stmt->execute();
            $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $stmt->closeCursor();
            return $results;
        }
        catch ( Exception $e )
        {
            die ( $e->getMessage() );
        }
    }
    //Loads all events for the month into an array
    private function _createEventObj()
    {
        /*Load the events array*/
        $arr = $this->_loadEventData();
        /* Create a new array, then organize the events by the day of the month on which they occur*/
        $events = array();
        foreach ( $arr as $event )
        {
            $day = date('j', strtotime($event['event_start']));
            try
            {
                $events[$day][] = new Event($event);
            }
            catch ( Exception $e )
            {
                die ( $e->getMessage() );
            }
        }
        return $events;
    }
    //Returns HTML markup to display the calendar and events Using the information stored in class properties
    public function buildCalendar()
    {
        /*Determine the calendar month and create an array of
        weekday abbreviations to label the calendar columns
        */
        $cal_month = date('F Y', strtotime($this->_useDate));
        $weekdays = array('Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue',
            'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat');
        /*Add a header to the calendar markup*/
        $html = "\n\t<h2>$cal_month</h2>";
        for ( $d=0, $labels=NULL; $d<7; ++$d )
        {
            $labels .= "\n\t\t<li>" . $weekdays[$d] . "</li>";
        }
        $html .= "\n\t<ul class=\"weekdays\">"
            . $labels . "\n\t</ul>";
        /*
        * Load events data
        */
        $events = $this->_createEventObj();
        $html .= "\n\t<ul>"; // Start a new unordered list
        for ( $i=1, $c=1, $t=date('j'), $m=date('m'), $y=date('Y');
              $c<=$this->_daysInMonth; ++$i )
        {
            /*Apply a "fill" class to the boxes occurring before
            the first of the month */
            $class = $i<=$this->_startDay ? "fill" : NULL;
            /* Add a "today" class if the current date matches
            the current date*/
            if ( $c==$t && $m==$this->_m && $y==$this->_y )
            {
                $class = "today";
            }
            /*Build the opening and closing list item tags*/
            $ls = sprintf("\n\t\t<li class=\"%s\">", $class);
            $le = "\n\t\t</li>";
            /*Add the day of the month to identify the calendar box*/
            if ( $this->_startDay<$i && $this->_daysInMonth>=$c)
            {
                /*
                * Format events data
                */
                $event_info = NULL; // clear the variable
                if ( isset($events[$c]) )
                {
                    foreach ( $events[$c] as $event )
                    {
                        $link = '<a href="view.php?event_id='
                            . $event->id . '">' . $event->title
                            . '</a>';
                        $event_info .= "\n\t\t\t$link";
                    }
                }
                $date = sprintf("\n\t\t\t<strong>%02d</strong>",$c++);
            }
            else { $date="&nbsp;"; }
            /*If the current day is a Saturday, wrap to the next row*/
            $wrap = $i!=0 && $i%7==0 ? "\n\t</ul>\n\t<ul>" : NULL;
            /*Assemble the pieces into a finished item*/
            $html .= $ls . $date . $le . $wrap;
        }
        /*Add filler to finish out the last week*/
        while ( $i%7!=1 )
        {
            $html .= "\n\t\t<li class=\"fill\">&nbsp;</li>";
            ++$i;
        }
        /*Close the final unordered list*/
        $html .= "\n\t</ul>\n\n";
        /* Return the markup for output*/
        return $html;
    }
}
?>
```

This is the php file that creates the array

```
<?php
/**
 * Stores event information
 */
class Event
{
    /**

     * The event ID
     *
     * @var int
     */
    public $id;
    /**
     * The event title
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $title;
    /**
     * The event description
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $description;
    /**
     * The event start time
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $start;
    /**
     * The event end time
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $end;
    /**
     * Accepts an array of event data and stores it
     *
     * @param array $event Associative array of event data
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($event)
    {
        if ( is_array($event) )
        {
            $this->id = $event['event_id'];
            $this->title = $event['event_title'];
            $this->description = $event['event_desc'];
            $this->start = $event['event_start'];
            $this->end = $event['event_end'];
        }
        else

        {
            throw new Exception("No event data was supplied.");
        }
    }
}
?>
```

AND finally this is the index file that outputs the calender

```
      <?php
/*
 * Include necessary files
 */
include_once '../sys/core/init.inc.php';
/*
 * Load the calendar for January
 */
$cal = new Calendar($dbo, "2013-02-01 12:00:00");


/*
 * Set up the page title and CSS files
 */
$page_title = "Events Calendar";
$css_files = array('style.css');
/*
 * Include the header
 */
include_once 'assets/common/header.inc.php';
?>
    <div id="content">
        <?php

        echo $cal->buildCalendar();

        ?>
    </div><!-- end #content -->
<?php
/*
 * Include the footer
 */
include_once 'assets/common/footer.inc.php';
?>
```

and this is the css

```
body {
background-color: #789;
font-family: georgia, serif;
font-size: 13px;
}
#content {
display: block;
width: 812px;
margin: 40px auto 10px;
padding: 10px;
background-color: #FFF;
-moz-border-radius: 6px;
-webkit-border-radius: 6px;
border-radius: 6px;
border:2px solid black;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 14px #123;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 14px #123;
box-shadow: 0 0 14px #123;
}
h2,p {
margin: 0 auto 14px;
www.it-ebooks.info
CHAPTER 4 ■ BUILD AN EVENTS CALENDAR
156
text-align: center;
}
ul {
display: block;
clear: left;
height: 82px;
width: 812px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
background-color: #FFF;
text-align: center;
border: 1px solid black;
border-top: 0;
border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
li {
position: relative;
float: left;
margin: 0;
padding: 20px 2px 2px;
border-left: 1px solid black;
border-right: 1px solid black;
width: 110px;
height: 60px;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: white;
}
li:hover {
background-color: #FCB;
z-index: 1;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #789;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #789;
box-shadow: 0 0 10px #789;
}
.weekdays {
height: 20px;
border-top: 2px solid black;
}
.weekdays li {
height: 16px;
padding: 2px 2px;
background-color: #BCF;
}
.fill {
www.it-ebooks.info
CHAPTER 4 ■ BUILD AN EVENTS CALENDAR
157
background-color: #BCD;
}
.weekdays li:hover,li.fill:hover {
background-color: #BCD;
-moz-box-shadow: none;
-webkit-box-shadow: none;
box-shadow: none;
}
.weekdays li:hover,.today {
background-color: #BCF;
}
li strong {
position: absolute;
top: 2px;
right: 2px;
}
li a {
position: relative;
display: block;
border: 1px dotted black;
margin: 2px;
padding: 2px;
font-size: 11px;
background-color: #DEF;
text-align: left;
-moz-border-radius: 6px;
-webkit-border-radius: 6px;
border-radius: 6px;
z-index: 1;
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
font-weight: bold;
font-style: italic;
}
li a:hover {
background-color: #BCF;
z-index: 2;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 6px #789;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 6px #789;
box-shadow: 0 0 6px #789;
}
```

I know this is long but I think my issue lies within the calender or db connection file, Id really appreciate some help, as I do not know PDO that well.
Thanks in advance

This is my db table structure
[image]

All of the code is taken from a book.

Comment: can you give us the schema of the database you're using?

Comment: @Kris, I have added a screenshot of my table structure

Comment: actually, come to look more closely at your screenshot, looks like the issue is in css somewhere. did you forget to link a stylesheet or something?

Comment: @Kris, I have managed to built most of the calender, but I still could not get it to display the events data. I included the basic calender code in my question because there is less code

Comment: but your lists are displaying as block items, meaning they take up the entire available width of the browser window and therefor display top down, while you want them left to right. you'll need some css to fix that and i don't see any in the code. that's why i think you're missing something. In the screenshot, the event _is_ next to the date, the dat just isn't next to the weekday. if you put the actual html on a jsfiddle i believe i can help with that. though it should also be in the book

Comment: @Kris, ok thank you , I will put everything on jsfiddle quickly and send you the link

Comment: @Kris, I have updated my question with the css file and updated the index file.

Comment: @Kris there is one more issue, when I took the database connection code form the book it didnt work and i made some tweaks, in the question I put original version now, and when I try to display the calender with the original code from the book it gives this errorNotice: Undefined variable: db in C:\xampp\htdocs\sys\class\class.db_connect.inc.php on line 17

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25914/discussion-between-kris-and-elmify)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the file with the calendar class:

After the line that says `$date = sprintf("\n\t\t\t<strong>%02d</strong>",$c++);` you could add `$date .= $event_info;`